# How does Orbeon mediate PDF generation

Tags: orbeon

Running Orbeon 4.2.0.201305301915-PE

I've enabled form-based permissions via FB and have different behaviours for PDF and View processes. Ie. a user that has view permissions doesn't have PDF permissions. It appears that the PDF generation runs under a different security context, coz if I add read to "anybody" then it works.
This log shows a successful view operation:

```
2013-05-31 10:50:06,962 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:06,985 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 23
2013-05-31 10:50:07,113 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server-submit - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,119 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server-submit - Timing: 6
2013-05-31 10:50:07,131 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/parkers/test/view/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718 - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,144 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,151 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,166 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 22
2013-05-31 10:50:07,174 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 23
2013-05-31 10:50:07,236 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/parkers/test/view/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718 - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,244 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/data/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718/data.xml - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:07,259 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/data/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718/data.xml - Timing: 15
2013-05-31 10:50:07,260 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/parkers/test/data/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718/data.xml - Timing: 24
2013-05-31 10:50:07,278 WARN  XFormsServer  - xxf:instance() - instance not found {instance id: "fb-variables"}
2013-05-31 10:50:07,287 WARN  XFormsServer  - instance() - instance not found {instance id: "error-summary-control-bottom$fr-errors-instance"}
2013-05-31 10:50:07,337 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/parkers/test/view/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718 - Timing: 206
```

followed by an unsuccessful PDF generation:

```
2013-05-31 10:50:12,908 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/parkers/test/pdf/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718 - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:12,921 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:12,930 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:12,950 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/exist/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 20
2013-05-31 10:50:12,959 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/persistence/crud/parkers/test/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 38
2013-05-31 10:50:12,997 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/parkers/test/pdf/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718", status-code: "403"}
2013-05-31 10:50:13,003 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/parkers/test/pdf/b4a1a6b9e8a497e54d005e8731a68f51b7262718 - Timing: 95
2013-05-31 10:50:13,021 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Received request
2013-05-31 10:50:13,048 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-server - Timing: 26
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue you are describing. I create a form with the following permissions:

[image: permission]

Then log in as a user with role `a`, go to the new page for the form, save, load the summary page as a user in group `b`, and on the summary page see the following:

[image]

There, both buttons (*Review* and *PDF*) work fine, and if I go the *view* page, and there click on the *PDF* button, it works as well. If you are following other steps, feel free to update your question and post a comment to this answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I forgot to say I'm using the full portlet in Liferay 6.1.1. CE.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I will attempt to reproduce this. It might be a few days though.

Comment: Understood, thanks Erik. I assume it's something to do with the blank target opening in a non-Lifray context, IMHO?

Comment: Jez, forgot this question entirely. Is it still current?

Comment: Hi Erik. Yes, still same scenario with 4.3. When using Liferay Roles for permission based access, for PDF generation to work, read access is needed for 'anybody'